# XMLHttpRequest call backend python cgi script, python script not responding

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, cgi

I wrote a simple html file with form data and used XMLHttpRequest to post data to another python cgi script, but for some reason, the python script does not do what it is supposed to do. After passing the data from the html to python, the cgi script is supposed to create a text file and write a line into that text file, but the text file is not created after I click the 'Run' button. Any idea why this happened? Here's the html code and python script:

----HTML----

```
<html>
<head> <title> TEST </title> </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function run(){
        var facPath = document.forms["inputParams"]["FacPath"].value;
        var facId   = document.forms["inputParams"]["IdName"].value;

        var xhttp; 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/processRequest.py", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-
        urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("facPath="+facPath+"&facId="+facId);
    }
</script>

<body>
<P>
<form name="inputParams" >
Factor File Path <BR>
<input type="text" name="FacPath"> <BR><BR>

Factor ID Name <BR>
<input type="text" name="IdName"> <BR><BR>

<input type="button" value="Run" name="submit" onclick="run()">
</form>
</P>
<div id="response"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

----Python cgi script----

```
import cgi
import sys

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
facPath = form.getvalue('facPath','None')
if facPath:
    with open(r'C:\Users\XXX\inputSpec.txt','w') as outputFile:
        outputFile.write(facPath)

sys.stdout.write("Status: 200 OK\n")
sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: text/plain\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("Success.")
```

Do I need to make the python script executable? Or is it some other reason? Thank you.

Comment: When I run the python script from command line, it does the job, i.e. creating the text file and write 'None' to it.

Comment: Anybody has any idea? I've spend a day on this, but have not figured out why. Really appreciate it!